# Django: I have a Profile model, and I want the slug for the profile detail page to be username, which is stored in User model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a website where every User has an associated Profile instance, because I want the User model to only handle authentication-related user functions and the Profile model to handle everything else (such as user-uploaded images, etc.) Profile has a User OneToOneField. However, I want to be able to access each profile's detail page using the url pattern site/profile/[username]/. This is impossible without storing the username in both the User and the Profile models, since the slug_field for the Profile DetailView has to be a primary key of Profile, and the username is a field of User. Is there any way to do this without storing the username in two different places?

Answer (score 2):

It is not needed. You can try this way.

**In urls.py**

```
from .import views

url(r'^(?P<usernameslug>[-_\w]+)/detail/$',views.detailprofile)
```

**Assuming Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    . . . .
    . . . .
```

**In views**

```
def detailprofile(request,usernameslug):
    profile=Profile.objects.get(user__username=usernameslug)
```

Comment: @Vik78, If the solution worked for you please vote up and select and if still any problem is there let me know by comments below. Thanks for all the cooperation